# Is it possible to change text on xml button?

Tags: android, xml, button

**If I have an xml button in a file called test.xml like this:**

```
  <Button
  android:id="@+id/newgame"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="New Game"
  />
```

**Is it possible to change the "New game" text to something else? I have to do this many times. 
The big problem is: I have to do it from inside a java file! Is that even possible?**

Comment: it's possible to achieve, where your getting error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

1) Get a reference to the Button

2) use the setText method to give text a new value

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.newgame);
button.setText("Something Else");
```

Answer (score 0):

definitly buddy,this type of question shoul not be ask for smart phones ,u can do it by update in xml as well as by java coding
ex....
Button buttontext = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setText("this is new text");
or in xml..

in xml it would be static for make it dynamic,set text in java class..
thanks